# Problem using PostMessage to display a message box

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, messagebox, postmessage

In my dialog `CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::OnInitDialog` class I do the following:

```
// ...
if (ReadReportFromFile() && IsModified())
{
    // The report will only be "modified" if we have updated the special events
    ::PostMessage(GetSafeHwnd(), theApp.UWM_REFRESHED_SPECIAL_EVENTS_MSG, NULL, NULL);
}
```

That, in turn triggers:

```
afx_msg LRESULT CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::OnUwmRefreshedSpecialEvents(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CString strMessage;
    
    strMessage.LoadString(IDS_STR_NEW_SPECIAL_EVENTS_ADDED );

    for (const auto& sEvent : m_listNewSpecialEvents)
    {
        strMessage.AppendFormat(_T("%s: %s\n"),
            (LPCTSTR)sEvent.datEvent.Format(VAR_DATEVALUEONLY),
            (LPCTSTR)sEvent.strEvent);
    }

    AfxMessageBox(strMessage, MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

    return 0;
}
```

But I have noticed that I can still close my editor window and that popup message is still visible to the main application window. I anticipated that it would be modal to my editor window.

I have also tried using `PostMessage(theApp...)` instead of the `::` scope version and it makes no difference.

There are reasons why I am posting a message to display the message box because doing `AfxMessageBox` directly messages up my web browser control from rendering on my main window.

So how can I post a message to simulate the display of a message box and it be relative the the dialog in question?

Comment: [`MessageBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) allows you to specify the owning window.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, I just tried `::MessageBox(GetSafeHwnd(), strMessage, L"Title", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);` and it does indeed work. But my application uses `CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::DoMessageBox` to customize the look and feel of the message box. When I use `::MessageBox` it is no longer is consistent.

Comment: And calling `theApp.DoMessageBox` is no different to calling `AfxMessageBox`.

Comment: If you need to specify a non-default owner window for the message box, you cannot call `AfxMessageBox`.

Comment: @IInspectable I getcha. Just frustrating. It seems to be because we are constructing and displaying the dialog at the point that we post the message in OnInitDialog. But as you say, ::MessageBox works the way we want, just without my styling.